Fantasy novel- teens create a map for school but create another world
I read a book in the 00s aimed at young teens (I think) about 2 teenage boys who had to create a map for a school assignment and ended up enjoying it so would still add to it after the deadline.
The map was of a medieval fantasy world and every other chapter would tell the lives of the people that live in the fantasy world.
I think there is a war in the map world and in the real world the teens argue with each other a lot as one of the boys doesn’t want to be involved in building the world anymore and the other is scared that he’d lose his friend if they stopped doing that together
I remember it having a lot of tense moments
The front cover was grey/ stone with a dagger on it and I think the title was just one word.
I can’t seem to find it
I borrowed it from the library in England, and think it might’ve been written by a British author but I’m not 100% sure on that

Found it elsewhere!
Traitors Game - B R Collins
